# JavaScript function returning undefined despite values being set

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've written two functions as shown below. The bottom one is returning 'undefined' for 'startAndEndDates' for some reason even though the console log above the return in findStartEndDates() is telling me the two values are set. What am I missing?

```
export function findBillingCycle(day_of_reservation) {
    let reservation_date = moment.utc(day_of_reservation).format();

    let fifteenth = moment();
    fifteenth = fifteenth.startOf('day');
    fifteenth = moment.utc(fifteenth);

    let fourteenth = moment();
    fourteenth = fourteenth.endOf('day');
    fourteenth = moment.utc(fourteenth);
    fourteenth.date(14);

    if (fifteenth.date() < 15) {
        fifteenth.subtract(1, 'month');
    } else {
        fourteenth.add(1, 'month');
    }
    fifteenth.date(15);

    let startAndEndDates = findStartEndDates(reservation_date, fifteenth, fourteenth);

    console.log(startAndEndDates);
    return startAndEndDates;
}


function findStartEndDates(reservation_date, fifteenth, fourteenth) {

    if (moment(reservation_date).isBefore(fifteenth)) {
        fifteenth = moment(fifteenth).subtract(1, 'month');
        fourteenth = moment(fourteenth).subtract(1, 'month');
    }
    if (moment(reservation_date).isAfter(fourteenth)) {
        fifteenth = moment(fifteenth).add(1, 'month');
        fourteenth = moment(fourteenth).add(1, 'month');
    }
    if (!moment(reservation_date).isBefore(fifteenth) && !moment(reservation_date).isAfter(fourteenth)) {
        console.log('returning  15th = ' + moment(fifteenth).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        console.log('returning 14th = ' + moment(fourteenth).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        return {
            fifteenth: fifteenth,
            fourteenth: fourteenth
        };
    } else {
        findStartEndDates(reservation_date, fifteenth, fourteenth);
    }
}
```

You can use the following as test data:

```
reservation_date: 2018-09-07T13:45:00Z
fifteenth: moment.utc("2018-06-15T05:00:00.000+00:00")
fourteenth: moment.utc("2018-07-14T04:59:59.999+00:00")
```

Update:
Found a workaround by creating the two other dates (fifteenth/fourteenth) in the same month that reservation_date takes place in. Then it's just a simple logic check to determine if I need to roll back or forward one month. I just do this all in one function so I don't need to rely on another function.

Comment: Please include what values you are using to achieve this result. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Your `findStartEndDates` function doesn't return anything in its `else` case. It looks like you're intending to do a recursive call, in which case it should be `return findStartEndDates(reservation_date, fifteenth, fourteenth)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to these lines in your `findStartEndDates` function:

```
    } else {
        findStartEndDates(reservation_date, fifteenth, fourteenth);
    }
```

You're making a recursive call in the `else` case, but you don't return the result of this recursive call. This means that the function gets called as intended, the `console.log()`s work as expected, but the return value is never passed down through the call stack so you end up with `undefined`.

You need to change the aforementioned lines of code into this:

```
    } else {
        return findStartEndDates(reservation_date, fifteenth, fourteenth);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is to due with the way you wrote your return, try the following:

```
var values = [fifteenth, fourteenth];
return values;
```

Comment: I tried creating a local object and returning that, but I still see undefined in the console. Also tried returning just a random string like "hi" and it's also coming as undefined.